# openmp with fftw gcc

Tags: gcc, openmp, fftw

I have a parallel for loop (with typically 1000 iterations) with multiple calculations.
At one point I need to make:

1. fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
   on a set of data.
2. again fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
   on another set of data.
3. again fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
4. make calculations on the data calculated by fftw
5. make fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d
6. again fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d
   Unfortunately, I cannot create the plans before entering in the parallel region.
   The number of data is always a factor of 2.
   The data to transform change at each iteration of the loop
   Even if I try to use the same plan, I need to update the data, and this create a mess because they are not private but shared if I understand correctly.

What is the solution?

Have a solution to the issue

Comment: This sounds like the outer loops shouldn't be parallel at all. Let FFTW do its work in parallel and possibly parallelize some other loops between the FFTW calls ("data parallelism").

Comment: "The number of data is always a factor of 2." I hope you mean power of two.

Comment: It would help if you were posting a code example instead of trying to describe the code with words. Ideally a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but at least an excerpt with the relevant parts.